# Should graphics directives and primitives form a 1-dimensional list or a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: graphics3d

Both of these inputs seem to give exactly the same output:

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}], Green, Cuboid[{1, 1, 1}]}]
Graphics3D[{{Red, Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}]}, {Green, Cuboid[{1, 1, 1}]}}]
```

In the first, the argument to Graphics3D is a 1-dimensional list, and the scope of each colour directive seems to be the primitives that follow until the next directive is encountered. In the second, the argument is a 2-dimensional array, where directives have been safely packaged together with the primitive to which they are supposed to apply.

Is either form preferred ? Does it ever make any difference which one uses ?

Comment: `Graphics` and `Graphics3D` process their input in a bit different way then the "ordinary" language. As first approximation, you may assume that it applies `Flatten` onto its first argument (if the first argument is a list). So, IMHO, it just does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Graphics` appear to follow the rules of object inheritance as follows:

The following command creates a `Red` rectangle with `Blue` edges then the second `Green` rectangle inherits the `Blue` edges of the first.

```
Graphics[{
    Red,
    EdgeForm[Blue],
    Rectangle[{-1,-1}],

    Green,
    Rectangle[{1,1}]
}]
```

We can overwrite the inherited blue edge for second by specifying explicitly.

```
Graphics[{
    Red,
    EdgeForm[Blue],
    Rectangle[{-1,-1}],

    EdgeForm[Orange],
    Green,
    Rectangle[{1,1}]
}]
```

Inheritance model goes deeper into the properties of the directives, for example here the thickness of the first `EdgeForm` is inherited by the second `EdgeForm`.

```
Graphics[{
    Red,
    EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.05],Blue}],
    Rectangle[{-1,-1}],

    EdgeForm[Orange],
    Green,
    Rectangle[{1,1}]
}]
```

If you don't want the rules of inheritance to apply to a certain directive you can enclose it with the graphics object then that directive will not move down the inheritance tree and apply to further incoming objects.

```
Graphics[{
    Red,
    {
        EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.05],Blue}],
        Rectangle[{-1,-1}]
    },

    EdgeForm[Orange],
    Green,
    Rectangle[{1,1}]
}]
```

These inheritance rules are necessary to make the code less verbose.

I have used `Graphics` for simplicity but the same inheritance rules should govern the `Graphics3D` as well.